# No order for event triggers in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage triggers to get notified when files get uploaded and removed.

That generally seems to work alright, but file replacements seem to be an issue as both events get fired but in no determined order. In that way I can first receive `onFinalize` and subsequently `onDelete`, which of course would eventual mean a deletion.

Neither in `ObjectMetaData` nor in `EventContext`, I could find any hint that would allow me to distinguish between a proper delete and a replacement.

Did I miss anything or is this a (known) bug with Firebase Storage?

---

Edit for clarification: Distinguishing between a replace and a delete is not my primary goal, but if I receive the delete after the create, it appears to me as if the file was deleted, when this actually only the old instance got deleted.

Comment: Can you explain why it matters whether the file is deleted permanently, or deleted then created, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions doesn't give any guarantees at all for the order in which your functions will process events.  This is true for all event providers, not just Cloud Storage.  (An ordering guarantee means that Cloud Functions would not be able to scale massively, which is one of its most important properties.)

Please read this page to get a sense of how difficult it is to guarantee ordering in scalable systems: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you have to design in terms of delete and create only. Currently the firebase API does not have a replacement operation, when you upload a file with same name it really is two operations : a deletion, and a creation. If there is any cleanup or bookkeeping that changes based on whether the deletion is temp or perm, it is up to the recipient to figure it out.

For example, you may have to wait some time before deciding whether an object was actually replaced instead of permanently deleted. So the deletion handler would have instead to queue the task related to perm deletion, but this task would either get cancelled when create received, or the task would check to see if the file is still there (on which case it assumes replacement).

Note that this can get a little complicated to make robust if a user can replace then delete then create within a short amount of time. Unless there is a really good reason to differentiate perm vs temp deletion, it may not be worth the trouble.